# Can I prevent a turned concentration spell from working by just ceasing concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Ring of Spell Turning lets the target turn the spell back on the caster:

> ...using the slot level, spell save DC, attack bonus, and spell casting ability of the caster.

The description is silent on who concentrates.

So if Hold Person was turned back on the caster, could the caster prevent the downsides of this by ceasing concentration? Or is concentration assumed by someone else?

Comment: Looks like the comment was already answered here, or similar one anyways: 
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100684/what-happens-when-a-command-spell-and-others-is-returned-by-a-ring-of-spell-tu?rq=1

Comment: That answer also includes concentration, I did comment on the accepted answer because there seems to be a minor ommision when it comes to incapacitation of the target, but other than that I believe this question's needs are addressed there. Unless the OP disagrees.